# how to post HTML code without the browser rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm to build a forum for the project, but right now I'm facing this problem where I want users to be able to post their `HTML` source code as it works in this `forum`.

> But the problem is that the code runs or scatters my design when retrieve from my DB.

I tried using `repalce()` in `jQuery` but I could only `replace < with &lt;` but I want a function to be able to replace others such as `>,",'` and `&` so my question is how can I update this function.

```
function convert(div){
  var str =  $(div).html();
  var str2 =  str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
  var sta =  $(div).html(str2);
  return sta;
}
```

The above code work to replace the `<` but when I try including `>,",'` and `&` in the function it will stop work how can i make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Stick it in [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) or [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tags, or both, and make sure you use `text()` when inserting the content to the tag

```js
function convert(div){
    var str =  $(div).html();
    var sta =  $('<code />', {text : str});

    return sta;
}

var result = convert( $('#test') );

$('#result').html(result)
```

```css
#result {
  white-space : pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span>
    <p>TEST</p>
  </span>
</div>
<br />
<div id="result">
```

`<code>` will preserve the code, and `<pre>` will preserve whitespace, but there's also the CSS `white-space` property, that can act as a `<pre>` tag using the `pre` setting

Comment: but is their way you show me how to achieve this using replace() in a function to replace all once the code is posted

Comment: There's alsways a way. You don't have to replace anything, as that won't work anyway, the entities are either converted to HTML, or outputted "as is", i.e. not as `>` or `<`. The way to do it without using the tags above, is to output the HTML as just plain text -> https://jsfiddle.net/bLu0jcd2/